# SeleniumLibrary not found in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I installed Robotframework, robotframework-seleniumlibrary successfuly. i run testcase then i have this error.i Used RED
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdNLe.png)

Comment: Please make your post in text and provide more details to make the issue reproducible. You may consider checking out the [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from help.

Comment: The screenshot shows you're using python 2.7. That is an unsupported version of python.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your issue comes from python not finding the rpaframework from python path. The RCC will do it for you if you set it to the conda.yaml file.